# Better pattern to pass third party exceptions to WCF service callers?

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, soapfault

I am developing a WCF solution that consumes some third party services. Most user inputs and actions are to be validated by the third party services, meaning that my service only knows something has gone wrong when it receives third party exceptions.

I need to set up something to translate and pass such exceptions to callers of my own service, because the original exceptions' messages are too technical for my callers though I do want them to know what has gone wrong.

The solution I am thinking of, is to use Microsoft Enterprise Library Exception Handling, with custom handlers, catch third party exceptions, and replace the original messages with more friendly messages (from a mapping table or alike) as well as assign my error code, then throw SOAP faults. The full list of third party exceptions is unknown, but I do know most of them - for the unknown ones I am planning to replace with a generic message and error code, and log the original exception.

I think this solution will work, but there may be better ways, thus am posting this question to seek your expertise. Please share your thoughts. My main goals are to have third party exceptions handled elegantly (easy to maintain the handling code) and messages translated (easily configurable translation settings).

Comment: Remember that WCF _never_ passes exceptions of any kind. It always produces faults. It sounds like you want to control the faults returned by your service. There is no magical way to do that.

Comment: I think you have landed on the optimal solution. This is broadly how I would approach it too.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I got the following solution.

(1) In the service access layer (from where I make calls to third party services) of my own service, whenever an exception or error is received from the third parties, it is passed on to a shared DLL, my error-rewrite library.

(2) The library looks up if such exception or error has a mapping configured (it attempts to match by error code, message, message regex, etc), from XML-based configurations. The below is an example configuration which instructs the library to translate a message like "Your request for item ItemABCD is invalid, because it has been assigned to another user: User1234" to something like "Item ItemABCD cannot be assigned to you" with my own error code Item1. The library takes the new error code and message to form a new Fault which can be further processed by my business logic layer.

```
<!-- Each block is the mapping for a certain source error -->
<ErrorMapping>
    <sourceErrorCode></sourceErrorCode>
    <sourceErrorMessage>Your request for item (\w{0,10}) is invalid, because it has been assigned to another user: (\w{0,10}).</sourceErrorMessage>
    <NewErrorCode>Item1</NewErrorCode>
    <NewErrorMessage>Item {0} cannot be assigned to you.</NewErrorMessage>
</ErrorMapping>
```

(3) If third parties have developed new exceptions or erros that have not been mapped yet, a default fault is used, and optionally the source error can be passed onto my user as is when there is no matching mapping.

(4) Error logging is configured in the main project's Enterprise Library logging block, if configured, source errors, as well as formed new errors, and mapping rules used, etc, are logged.

This is not the perfection solution, but it worked well for my needs, thus I am providing it here in case someone is looking for potential solutions for similar needs.

Comment: I'm curious - do you have clients of your WCF service which do different things when they receive different faults?

Comment: Yes, the service is to be consumed by a few different business partners, which may react to the same fault differently.

Comment: Right, but do they listen to all of the faults to which you map? I've never had the need for all of this ceremony, and I'm wondering why you clearly _do_ need it and I never have.

Comment: They will listen to all faults but make their own decisions on whether to handle or discard, and how to handle. The main goals for this rewriting include: (1) Rewrite the source messages (which usually take some in-deepth knowledge of the systems to fully understand) to be more end user friendly. (2) Hide certain information from source systems, e.g. our financial system. (3) Assign my own error code for ease of writing up troubleshooting, etc. (4) If I replace a third party system where source errors are from, with another one, the impact on my clients is small (they deal with my faults).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes better sense.